# Handle large code blocks sanely

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, code-block

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [View code in new window](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23611/view-code-in-new-window)

Large code blocks, including ones that are simply too wide for the browser, can make some questions difficult to read.  I suggest that clicking on a (non-inline) code block, or some handle associated with it, open that block up in a new window.  This would allow the window to be resized as needed to make the code legible and/or positioned so that you can refer to it when answering the question.  The same should be true in the question preview pane when editing an answer. As it is, with some questions, you need to scroll up/down to look at the question, then perhaps scroll up/down/sideways to view the code.

Comment: I like the current restrictions, but a popout button would be nice

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23611/view-code-in-new-window

Comment: @Jon - not an exact duplicate -- I'm suggesting a click on the code or a handle instead of a link, which would be more obtrusive and less desirable.

Comment: @tvanfosson: it's the same functionality with some minor UI interaction differences.

Comment: @voyager -- but perhaps the UI implications are why it's never been done.

Comment: @tvanfosson: and how could we select pieces of code? (I know it could be done, but it would add annoyance to that use case.)

Comment: @voyager -- that would be an argument to use a handle (code block icon), perhaps in the upper right corner.

Answer (score 1):

That would give less incentive for people to post small code blocks and format their code correctly.

If the post needs enough code to make you scroll, it's a mild fail. If the post is not formatted to 80 characters wide, as God intended, it's a major fail.

[image]

---

I find it rather funny how I have changed my opinion completely in a few months.

> Yes I agree.
>   [answered Sep 26 '09 at 20:54](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23611/view-code-in-new-window/23613#23613) - Ólafur Waage
>
> > *I'm voyager, and I approve this answer.* – voyager Sep 27 '09 at 18:42